# Permissions to run PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell, teamcity

We are running a PowerShell script as part of our automated build in TeamCity, but it fails with the following error:

```
[16:31:49][Step 1/1] File F:\<path>\sript.ps1 cann

[16:31:49][Step 1/1] ot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Pleas

[16:31:49][Step 1/1] e see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
```

I have the execution policy set to `Unrestricted` on this machine:

```
PS C:\> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Unrestricted
```

and I can run this very same script manually from the PS console, just the execution from TeamCity fails. Any ideas?

```
EDIT: As requested:
PS C:\Users\xxx> Get-ExecutionPolicy -List

                                                      Scope                                             ExecutionPolicy
                                                      -----                                             ---------------
                                              MachinePolicy                                                   Undefined
                                                 UserPolicy                                                   Undefined
                                                    Process                                                   Undefined
                                                CurrentUser                                                   Undefined
                                               LocalMachine                                                Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Duncan, the problem was that the Machine Policy was undefined. This setting can only by changed through group policy. Within Group Policy, navigate to Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | Windows PowerShell and configure the Turn On Script Execution setting and select execution policy.

More details: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/set-the-powershell-execution-policy-via-group-policy/

Answer (score 0):

There are three scopes for execution policy: Process, Current User, Local Machine. It sounds likely that you have overridden the execution policy for your own userid but not the machine and TeamCity may be running as a different user.

As @jscott said in his comment, you should do:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

to get a full list of execution policies. In particular check the setting for LocalMachine.

BTW, `Unrestricted` is a poor choice. `RemoteSigned` is better as it will allow locally created scripts to run unsigned but will require signing for any scripts downloaded from the web.